# Modify ms Access chart ValueAxis Minimum value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm struggling with charts in an Access report. The default Y axis minimum is zero, I would like to change this dynamically as the report loads.

I have tried a number of options using variations on the code below but to no avail. Could someone point me in the direction where I can access and modify the Y axis minimum value. I have tried to use **Chart.PrimaryValuesAxisMaximum** but this has always resulted in a 'Doesn't support this property or method' Error

Using Office Professional Plus 2019. VB 7.1

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Dim MyChart As Object
Dim MyAxis As ChartAxisCollection
Set MyChart = Me.Graph4
Debug.Print MyChart.Name 'This appears to show the chart is available
Set MyAxis = MyChart.ChartAxisCollection
For Each MyAxis In MyChart
    Debug.Print MyAxis.Count
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give example from my project which uses classic chart control, not Modern Charts. This procedure is called by a form button click and a report Detail section Format event.

```
Sub FormatVibGraph(strObject As String, strLabNum As String, booMetric As Boolean)
'format Vibratory graph form and report
Dim obj As Object
Dim gc As Object
Dim MinDD As Double
Dim MaxDD As Double
MinDD = Nz(DMin("Den", "GraphVibratory"), 0)
MaxDD = Nz(DMax("Den", "GraphVibratory"), 0)
If strObject Like "Lab*" Then
    Set obj = Reports(strObject)
Else
    Set obj = Forms(strObject).Controls("ctrVibratory").Form
End If
Set gc = obj("gphDensity")
gc.Activate
If MinDD > 0 Then
    With gc
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinDD
    If booMetric = True Then
        MaxDD = Int(MaxDD / 100) * 100 + 100
        MinDD = MaxDD - 1000
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxDD
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinDD
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 200
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 40
    Else
        MaxDD = Int(MaxDD / 5) * 5 + 5
        MinDD = MaxDD - 50
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxDD
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinDD
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 10
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 2
    End If
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    If booMetric = True Then
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Max. Dry Density, Kg/cu.m"
    End If
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    If booMetric = True Then
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Percent Passing 4.75 mm Sieve"
    End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

So your code might be simply:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
Dim MyChart As Object
Set MyChart = Me.Graph4
MyChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = something
End Sub
```